# wxPython : EVT_BUTTON on a portion of a panel

Tags: event-handling, wxpython, panel

Hello evryone :) I would like to capture click event in a blue box drawn inside a wx.Panel

I already know how to reacts to button click :

```
myButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, myHandler)
```

or

```
myFrame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, myHandler, myFrame.myConcernedButton)
```

But how must I do if I want to

1. Draw a blue square onto a Panel, what I can already manage, luckily.
2. Capture a EVT_BUTTON onto the blue square only, and not the whole panel ?

I think I should make a new class for my SquareBox, but :

1. What class should it be derived from ?
2. So far then, how to add event handling to that class ?

Thank you very much.

P.S : For the little history, I used to develop in Java & SWING

---

Edit :

As Mike Driscoll advised me, I tried to solve my problem with a PlateButton. But unfortunately, I did not managed to give the button the wanted dimension nor the wanted style (it changes its color when it is clicked, and I don't wan't this). Furthermore, it doesn't react at all to EVT_BUTTON event.

This is my attempt, thanks in advance :

```
import wx
from wx.lib.platebtn import PlateButton

class Square(PlateButton):

    def __init__(self, parent, size, pos):
        PlateButton.__init__(self, parent, size = size, pos = pos)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,255))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Reactive square application",
            size = (300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        square1 = Square(panel, size=(60,60), pos=(80,50))
        square2 = Square(panel, size=(60,60), pos=(80,120))
        square1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSquareClick)

    def OnSquareClick(self, event):
        dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, "You clicked on square !!!",
            "Hit has been done", wx.OK)
        dialog.Show(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a custom widget. There's an article on the wiki about this topic here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls

Look at the source for AquaButton or PlateButton as those are custom controls too.

Comment: It seems that the page http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib-module.html is better documented that the page http://www.wxpython.org/onlinedocs.php, where I was used to go. So I've just added it to my browser favorites.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind to the panel then check the coordinates of the event.

Comment: I did not precise enough what I want to do. Your solution could be a solution : but it could be messy if I wanted to show two "clones" of BlueSquare. So, can i handle button event with a BlueSquare class ?